# SQL datetime to C# string and back to SQL datetime

Tags: c#, .net, sql, datetime

I have a webservice method that gets data from sql of the format
**2012-11-18 11:21:03** when i save it to C# string it becomes this format: **18.11.2012 11:21:03**
How do i change it back to the SQL format **2012-11-18 11:21:03** ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Parse it into a dateTime again

```
DateTime myTime = DateTime.Parse(myString);
```

and back into a proper to string

```
myTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Or just read it into a datetime and cut out the middleman.

Comment: I would use DateTime myTime = DateTime.ParseExact(myString, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

Answer (score 2):

You can get the universally sortable string format (which looks like the one used by SQL server) by using the format string `"u"` like this:

```
var dateTimeString = String.Format("{0:u}", yourDateTime);
```

Comment: Includes a "Z" , for example '2017-02-19 12:21:02Z'

Answer (score 0):

Simply run the below code,

```
var newDateTime = oldDateTime.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Its just converting it back to the `SQL Format DATETIME`

Comment: Doing that will strip out the time component of 'oldDateTime', and only works if oldDateTIme was already a datetime to begin with

Answer (score 0):

Trouble with Dates as strings is they are ambiguous and the formats can vary based on where you are in the world, or even local machine settings.  You might assume a date string is yyyy-mm-dd but what if it is actually yyyy-dd-mm?  Some dates will appear to work and some will be invalid.

In other words is 2013-02-10 the 10th of February or is it the 2nd of October?  If it is just a string you have no way of knowing for sure what was intended.

Your best bet as suggested by #Haedrian is to store in a DateTime C# object, not a string.  That way it is never ambiguous and you have access to various date specific functions.  If you must store as a string you can convert back to a date as above or use

```
DateTime.TryParse(datestring, out dateVariable);
```

which won't throw an exception for an invalid format.  Depends if you want exceptions!

Also I would suggest if you must use strings to use a 3 character month in strings, which again eliminates the ambiguity, e.g.

```
"dd-MMM-yy hh:mm tt"
```

Comment: *If it is just a string you have no way of knowing for sure what was intended.* If only there were a way to **ParseExact** ly the format that you wanted